# in Android is there any way to wrap Linkify Texts?

Tags: android, text, webview, linkify

I want to show the clickable text instead of using the url in webview. for example my text will be google and when user clicks on it it will start action_view intent to google's url. is it possble?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android:linkfy attribute and set it top true to make the urls linkfy by default in your textview.